# Then after evaluate always returns an object

Tags: javascript, nightmare

No matter what I return in `evaluate`, `then` always has this `value`:

```
{ bottom: 93,
  height: 20,
  left: 75,
  right: 249,
  top: 73,
  width: 174 }
```

My code:

```
nightmare
            .evaluate(() => true)
            .then(value => {
                console.log(value);
            });
```

It maybe because I run same methods in a loop(`asyncjs.times()`)?

Answer (score 0):

> It maybe because I run same methods in a loop?

This might be the case. You have to be careful when doing stuff inside a loop with Nightmare. I found [this](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) bit of documentation that helped me a lot.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250732/nightmare-js-error-search-failed-nothing-responds-to-goto/40291796#40291796) may also be of some help.

Comment: Thanks pipo_dev, I'll have a look at those links. I don't have the issue anymore but I find them handy.