# web scrapy by nightmare about loop ,output is not same every time

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
var fs  = require('fs');
vo = require('vo');
var result;
nightmare
    .goto('http://jufa-kyusyu.jp/teams/')
    .wait(1000)
    .evaluate(function () {
     var options = document.querySelectorAll('option'),i;
     var values =[]
     for (i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
        values.push(options[i].value)
        }
        return values;
    })
    .then(function (values) {
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(values[i] == "#") values[i] = "/teams/181.html";
    nightmare
      .goto("http://www.jufa-kyusyu.jp"+values[i])
      .evaluate(function () {
      var abc =     document.querySelector('iframe[class="autoHeight"]').src.toString()
      return abc;
    }) 
      .then(function (result) {
console.log(result)
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });} 
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

I want to scrapy the web information by nightmarejs looply.I dont know why have two result link is same and the result is changed in running every time.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful when working with async calls inside a loop with Nightmare

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250732/nightmare-js-error-search-failed-nothing-responds-to-goto/40291796#40291796) and [this](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) detailed explanation about the concept.

The main idea can be sumarized by this sentence:

> Executing the operations in series requires arranging them to execute
>   in sequential order

The documentation shows how to achieve that [using plain, vanilla js](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md#vanilla-js) and also [with vo](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md#using-vo)

Here is a sneak peek on how to solve this loop issue with plain Javascript:

```
var urls = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com'];
urls.reduce(function(accumulator, url) {
  return accumulator.then(function(results) {
    return nightmare.goto(url)
      .wait('body')
      .title()
      .then(function(result){
        results.push(result);
        return results;
      });
  });
}, Promise.resolve([])).then(function(results){
    console.dir(results);
});
```

Basically what you need to do is queue all your calls in a list and trigger them using `Promise.resolve`